# Selecting taxonomy term in article and showing all articles titles associated with this term

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type article and when editing an article there should be a field where you can select a taxonomy term of a specific vocabulary.

When viewing the article it should show a list of titles of all articles associated with the selected taxonomy term. I know how to make a select field and also a view to show the titles. But how do I send the selected term to the view and how do I display the view in the article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** Create a **View block**, when you create it use `Show: Content`.

**2)** Under Advanced **Contextual Filters** add `Has taxonomy term ID`

**3)** Select `provide default value` Type: `Taxonomy term ID from URL` (this will automatically grabs the term from your node) If you want, you can limit the terms by vocab.

Even if your tax term reference field is limited to 1, maybe you should set it up as if it was unlimited, in case your client later wants to allow more than 1 value.

Change the **multiple-value handling** option to the 2nd one, share any term.

Scroll down to MORE and check mark allow multiple values.

[image]

Click Apply, to save the settings.

---

Now you want to **exclude** the current Article (node) from the list. No point in showing the Article the visitor is already viewing/reading.

**4)** Add another **contextual filter** of `ID`

**5)** `Provide default value` Type: `Content ID from url` (automatically grabs the ID from your node).

**6)** Scroll all the way down, and click on MORE, and check mark `Exclude`.

[image]

So your Advanced section should look like this:

[image]

---

To place the block in your article, there are several ways.

Go to `admin/structure/block` and click on Place Block, search for your View Block and click on Place Block.

In the configuration, under Visibility settings, select Content Types and check mark your content type.

[image]

**Site Note:** There are other ways to insert/place your view:

- Through a template file.
- Using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and or [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) (Note: I am not 100% sure on this as I have not played much with these modules in D8, in D7 I know you can).

Comment: Wow, this is amazing thank you! What would have to be changed if there was the possibility to select more than one taxonomy term on the content edit page?

Comment: I am on mobile ATM. I'll update the answer later. In step 3, you sroll down and click MORE and check mark Allow multiple values.

Comment: It doesn't work, now it doesn't show any titles

Comment: In step 3, change the **multiple-value handling** option to the 2nd one, share any term.

Comment: Still doesn't show anything :(

Comment: `Still doesn't show anything :(` Are u referring to in the View preview? Because it is normal for your preview to be blank since the edit View URL has no terms. Just place the View block in your article, when you go to/read your article, the titles will show up then.

Comment: No, I already placed the block. When I select one taxonomy term it shows the titles correctly, when I select two, nothing appears.

Comment: ok, give me a few mins to test.

Comment: You must of gone wrong somewhere, I tested here https://rgr9h.ply.st/node/3 and works as expected. Feel free to login: `admin2` and pass: `admin2` See the Orange Juice (/node/3) as the main example.

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake: I was adding the block within the taxonomy term view instead of creating a new view. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the placement of the block, I found another interesting thread:
[How to create a field that references a Views Block display in D8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198623/how-to-create-a-field-that-references-a-views-block-display-in-d8)

So I tried using the modules

1) "Views Reference Fields", so you can add a field to a node to insert a specific view, especially in conjunction with Paragraphs. Unfortunately it didn't show anything on my test site. Also with Paragraphs you have to save the node and reopen before you can select a display of the selected view.

2) "Block field", so you an add a field to a node to insert a block, which can also be a block of a view. It worked for me with and without paragraphs.