# How can I make a view block of related products?

Tags: commerce

I have read through the issue queue and read all kinds of documentation and made all kinds of settings in Views Contextual Filter and no luck at all. What can be the definitive way to make a Views block of related Commerce 2 products?

My products are tagged to taxonomy terms of which the taxonomy vocabulary is referenced on the product. I now tried to make a Views block to make contextual filter such that if viewing a product you can find a block of other products belonging to same taxonomy term.

No settings are working.

Comment: can you look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTRiJR7MiXQ but when the guy says "node" pretend he says "product"

Comment: Similar to [Selecting taxonomy term in article and showing all articles titles associated with this term](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224817/selecting-taxonomy-term-in-article-and-showing-all-articles-titles-associated-wi/224819#224819)

Comment: Thank you @taggartJ I already tried this approach but the problem is Commerce 2 does not use nodes so products are not nodes and the default value filter does not behave out of the box the way it does for content nodes.

Comment: Thank you @NoSssweat this approach didn't work for me for the same reason I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

This patch solved this issue, https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3015347#comment-13310494